# How to convert a unicode into a list of unicode

Tags: python, string, list, python-unicode

I have a variable, which is a unicode:

```
u'["123.45", "124,67", "111.2"]'.
```

Now I want to convert it into a list of unicode like

```
[u"123.45", u"124,67", u"111.2"]
```

I didn't see any similar examples online. I have been trying encode, decode, str but all no results. The tricky part is that it looks like the first list itself is a unicode.
Any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `ast.literal_eval()`?

Comment: This looks like Python 2. Is it really the version you are using ?

Comment: It is indeed python2, but besides ast.literal_eval(), no other solution?

Comment: It's perfectly valid JSON as well, so you could use `json.loads`.